# How can I prevent phantoms spawning with commands in 1.15+?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I do not like phantoms. How can I prevent them from spawning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `/gamerule doInsomnia false`, which turns off phantom spawning at nighttime. [Full list of commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/gamerule)